# JavaFX error: class 'MediaView' could not be found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I am currently starting to work with JavaFX using IntelliJIDEA and Maven.
Until now, everything worked out fine and I was able to use all the elements I needed.

But now I ran into a problem when I tried to add the MediaView element to play a video within my application interface. The element was displayed in SceneBuilder, but the MediaView class could not be accessed in my controller class: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0LZA.png)

And that even though I added the specific Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>21-ea+24</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried searching in the internet, on youtube, I asked ChatGPT, tried it with making a new intelliJ project, I tried adding the javafx.media library manually into my Project Structure and even the whole JavaFX-Lib.
And I also tried adding VM-options but I'm honest with you, that I had no clue what I was doing there.
Someone even asked this question once on Stack overflow, but its solution did not help me.

Oh, and if it helps in any way, here is the exact error message in the console: [error-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6XL8.png)
It's german, but it's basically saying: "symbol not found, symbol: class MediaView"

I am pretty new to all that informatics stuff and I would really appreciate it if someone has another suggestion for me.

Comment: [Do not post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2189127)

Comment: When you post the code (as text, [correctly formatted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)), include the relevant imports.

Comment: I don't recommend using `ea` early access versions.